# diagonalization addition

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose that A and B are diagonalizable and have the same eigenvectors. Prove that A+B is diagonalizable.
I get $A=PD_AP^{-1}$ and $B=PD_BP^{-1}$, and A+B = $PD_AP^{-1}+PD_BP^{-1}$, but how do I combine these two terms?

Answer (score 1):

$$A+B = PD_AP^{-1} + PD_BP^{-1} = P(D_A + D_B)P^{-1}$$

The last step is valid because:
$$P(D_A + D_B)P^{-1}=(P(D_A + D_B))P^{-1} = (PD_A + P D_B)P^{-1} = PD_AP^{-1} + PD_BP^{-1}$$

Comment: can you explain why? Thank you!

Comment: I have added an extra line. All I am using is that $A(B+C) = AB+AC$ and $(A+B)C = AC+BC$ for matrices $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalisable then it means there must be a basis of eigenvectors which are shared by $B$. Call them $v_1,...,v_n$.

Since $A,B,A+B$ are linear it is sufficient to check the behaviour on a basis, in the case the eigenvectors.

Suppose the eigenvalues corresponding to the $v_k$ are $\lambda_k^A,\lambda_k^B$, then we have

$(A+B)v_k = (\lambda_k^A+\lambda_k^B) v_k$ and so we see that the $v_k$ are eigenvectors of $A+B$ and since they form a basis, $A+B$ is diagonalisable
(using the matrix $V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$).

Comment: I know other answers continued from the user's attempt and you suggest an attempt that is seemingly divergent from the user's attempt, but it would be helpful for the sake of completeness if you finished the user's approach and then presented your own answer, since the question is essentially : "how do I combine these terms" and that wasn't quite explained. I'm pretty fine with the rest, of course.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: I don't wish to since the other answers kind of go through what I'd have anyway , so  thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

then $(A+B)P,=P D_A  + P D_B$ , then left multiply by $P^{-1}$, then revert the multiplications